# Whenever I install or update I get this error (screenshot added below) The MATLAB interface needs to know where MATLAB is installed?

Tags: apt, dpkg, matlab

In the screen it asks for matlab installed directory, I don't have MATLAB and I don't want to buy it.

[image]

**I'm running ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

Comment: what program are you trying to install?

Comment: I was trying to install 'tree', sudo apt-get install tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have tried to install the package `matlab-support`, which is available in the Ubuntu repositories. Without MatLab, it is useless, but keeps popping up.

---

Run the command

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge matlab-support
```

and you're done.